# ruby not found but 2.4.0 installed by rvm indeed

Tags: ruby, rvm

I am new to Ruby. Following the tutorials: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rvm-on-ubuntu-16-04 and https://scotch.io/tutorials/a-crash-course-in-ruby.

The output of terminal (OS ubuntu 16.04):

```
me@xxx:~$ rvm list

rvm rubies

=* ruby-2.4.0 [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default

me@xxx:~$ ruby --version
The program 'ruby' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install ruby
me@xxx:~$ rvm use ruby-2.4.0

RVM is not a function, selecting rubies with 'rvm use ...' will not work.
```

Any idea why? Thanks.

**UPDATE**

```
me@xxx:~$ rvm alias create default 2.4.0
Creating alias default for ruby-2.4.0....
me@xxx:~$ ruby -v
The program 'ruby' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install ruby
```

**UPDATE2**

Part of ~/.bashrc

```
# Add RVM to PATH for scripting. Make sure this is the last PATH variable change.
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.rvm/bin"
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

The last line added by me just now. Still not working.

Comment: Did you add `rvm` path to your `~/.bashrc` ? If not then add `[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"` on `~/.bashrc` that may remove `RVM is not a function, selecting...` error.

Comment: solved. Thanks...

Answer (score 0):

Theres different ways to install ruby, you can try with rbenv, i did it with this guide and it worked perfectly, maybe u can give it a shot:

https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/16.04

Answer (score 0):

Generally, you just have to make sure that your bash is run with the option

```
--login
```

(in the config of your terminal) and restart your console.

Answer (score 0):

maybe following code can help you.but I don't know how to deal with it perpetually.

```
$ source ~/.bashrc
$ source ~/.bash_profile
```